# Maven site deploy issue

Tags: java, maven, deployment, jdk6

I am using the `maven site-deploy` command. I am using `maven 2.2.1` with `jdk 6`.

I get the following error:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Wagon protocol '' doesn't support directory copying
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Wagon protocol '' doesn't support directory copying
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.SiteDeployMojo.execute(SiteDeployMojo.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    ... 17 more`
```

The pom.xml has the following distribution Management section:

```
    <site>
        <id>app123</id>
        <url>/app/il3/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/webapps/build/app123</url>
    </site>
```

Please advise.

Thanks,
B

Comment: Apart from that i would recommend to upgrade http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're just having trouble to configure your maven `<site>` tag. at the `URL` from the official documentation it states:

> url: This is the core of the repository element. It specifies both the location and the transport protocol to be used to transfer a built artifact (and POM file, and checksum data) to the repository.

And you're missing your transport protocol on your URL. Therefore the

> Wagon protocol '' doesn't support directory copying

Here is the list of supported protocols, from their [site](http://maven.apache.org/wagon/):

- File
- HTTP
- HTTP lightweight
- FTP
- SSH/SCP
- WebDAV

So why don't you try specifying a valid URL? `<url>file://var/<url>`
Here are some more [examples and a explanation](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/fileurl.html)

Comment: That worked! Thanks. I should have spotted that :-).

Answer (score 2):

I've got a similar problem but for protocol **http** `Wagon protocol 'http' doesn't support directory copying` on a nexus site.

I solved it by switching to dav protocol. It needs to be added as extension.

```
<project>
   ...
   <distributionManagement>
      <site>
        <id>uumds-site-repository</id>
        <name>Uumds Site Repository</name>
        <!--
        <url>http://vs-b1-repo1:8081/nexus/content/sites/uumds/${project.groupId}-${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</url>
        -->
        <url>dav:http://vs-b1-repo1:8081/nexus/content/sites/uumds/${project.groupId}-${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</url>
      </site>
  </distributionManagement>
  ...
  <build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-webdav-jackrabbit</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
  ...
  </build>
</project>
```